# Maximum allowed requests per session exception - Work around

Tags: c#, for-loop, nosql, ravendb

I am getting a exception "Maximum allowed requests per session (30) is reached" etc..
I am trying to run a RavenDB query inside a "for loop" and I am wondering how I can get around doing this. The code is below.

```
  using (var session = store.OpenSession())
        {          
            var MovieList = session.Query<Movies>()                                    
                                 .ToList();         

            foreach (var movie in MovieList)
            {
               int NumByState = session.Query<Theaters>()
                                .Where(x => x.State == movie.State)
                                .Count();

               string MovieName = movie.MovieName;
             }                     

        }
```

The records in the query are in the 100s and I need to run the count query inside of for loop, I cant see another way to run the query outside of the loop.. because I need to run this query for each of the items in the list. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{          
    var MovieList = session.Query<Movies>()                                    
        .ToList();
    var states = session.Query<Theaters>()
        .ToList()
        .GroupBy(x => x.State)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());         

    foreach (var movie in MovieList)
    {
        int NumByState = states.ContainsKey(movie.State)
            ? states[movie.State]
            : 0;

        string MovieName = movie.MovieName;
    }
}
```

This will also be a lot faster than querying the DB hundreds of times - especially if the DB is accessed over a network.

Comment: thank you for the response. I am getting a "Method not supported: GroupBy" exception at var states =... GroupBy...

Comment: @ZVenue: I updated the answer so that the client does the grouping now.

Comment: "Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String'" error after making changes..

Comment: Updated it again. I hope it'll work now, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Sorry, but that simply doesn't work if you have more than 128 theaters.

Comment: Computing the numbers by state in memory is a big smell. As @Daniel stated, it even breaks when the number of movies and/or states increases. Shifting the computation to an index is much better.

Comment: In a good DBMS you can do a `group x by x.State select new { State = x.Key, Count = x.Count() }` directly on the database without creating an index at all ;)

Comment: @Tobias you can do that in RavenDB, you just need to use a Map/Reduce index. BTW most document databases use this approach, although as you say it would be nicer is you could just write "group by" code and have it do it for you automaticially

Comment: @Tobias I have noticed.. this does not get all records..It should return about 20 theaters with counts .. but I get only 5.      why?        var states = session.Query<Theaters>()
        .ToList()
        .GroupBy(x => x.State)
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

Comment: Are the theaters spread over 5 states? Since you want to know how much theaters are in each state (to know in how many theaters a movie runs, I suppose), I count how much theaters are in each state and discard all other data. `states.Sum(x => x.Value)` should yield the value you are expecting.

Comment: Got it.. because it gets only 128 by default.. and in that I am grouping.. never mind.

Comment: Actually in response to your latest comment - theaters are across couple of dozen states..more than 5 for sure.

Answer (score 4):

ZVenue, this is a perfect example for a Multi Maps / Reduce index:

```
public class MoviesWithTheatersCount : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<MoviesWithTheatersCount.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public int TheaterCount { get; set; }
    }

    public MoviesWithTheatersCount()
    {
        AddMap<Movie>(movies => from movie in movies
                                select new
                                           {
                                               State = movie.State,
                                               MovieName = movie.Name,
                                               TheaterCount = 0
                                           });

        AddMap<Theater>(theaters => from theater in theaters
                                    select new
                                               {
                                                   State = theater.State,
                                                   MovieName = (string)null,
                                                   TheaterCount = 1
                                               });

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.State
                            into g
                            select new
                                       {
                                           State = g.Key,
                                           MovieName = g.Select(x => x.MovieName != null).First(),
                                           TheaterCount = g.Sum(x => x.TheaterCount)
                                       };
    }
}
```

As a side-note: you should not query with an unbounded result set - use `.Take()` instead.

Comment: I see your point and merits of using an index ..  Thank you for the code sample..

Comment: AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask is not recognized..AbstractIndexCreationTask is. Tried using Raven.Abstractions.Indexing;
using Raven.Client.Indexes;  what am I missing?

Comment: The type AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<TReduceResult> is inside Raven.Client.Indexes.

Comment: Multimaps are not going to work in the older build I am working with. Is there another way to do this .. without having to strain the db with other posted solutions .. I really cant upgrade the build at this point

Comment: I fear there's no alternative to that, at least I can't think of one. You can use a normal Map/Reduce index to count Movies and Theaters per State, but it's not possible to put them together without using a second Map function. Btw - why can't you upgrade to the more recent build? Upgrading should be painless...

Answer (score 1):

So as suggested by @Tobias a better method, but you can change the maximum number of request. This is done by setting the MaxNumberOfRequestPerSession Property. This can be set in the session.Advanced/MaxNumberOfRequestPerSession.

The idea and details here: http://ravendb.net/documentation/safe-by-default

Comment: Good to know how to change that setting.. If I want to use this solution, I might have to set the number high to 300. Is that very high? and also if slowness is only the concern, what if I schedule this only to run in DB 'no activity' hours or non peak hours.

Comment: Please don't do this. There are good reasons for that not being the default setting.

Comment: @DanielLang I agree with you but there is a reason for exposing and in some cases you should, but it should be avoided and the reason why I included the link.

Comment: Brad, you are right, there _are_ scenarios. However, the only two I can think of are migrations and bulk import/export. Having more than 10-15 request per Session in a production application is _always_ wrong because it has such a huge impact on performance.